# Python Pandas adds column header as entry instead of actual data after adding new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an unexpected behavior when adding a new row to a pre-allocated DataFrame after I added a new column to this DataFrame.

I created the following minimal example (using Python 3.6.5 and Panda 0.23.0):

First, I create a pre-allocated DataFrame with 3 columns

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('A', 'B', 'C'), index=range(5))

# The resulting DataFrame df
#     A    B    C
#0  NaN  NaN  NaN
#1  NaN  NaN  NaN
#2  NaN  NaN  NaN
#3  NaN  NaN  NaN
#4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Then, I am adding a few rows, which works like expected

```
new_row = {'A':0, 'B':0, 'C':0}
df.loc[0] = new_row
df.loc[1] = new_row
df.loc[2] = new_row

# The resulting DataFrame df
#     A    B    C
#0    0    0    0
#1    0    0    0
#2    0    0    0
#3  NaN  NaN  NaN
#4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Then, I am adding a new column with a default value

```
df['D'] = 0

# The resulting DataFrame df
#     A    B    C  D
#0    0    0    0  0
#1    0    0    0  0
#2    0    0    0  0
#3  NaN  NaN  NaN  0
#4  NaN  NaN  NaN  0
```

And eventually, adding a new row after adding the new column, I get this

```
new_row = {'A':0, 'B':0, 'C':0, 'D':0} 
df.loc[3] = new_row

# The resulting DataFrame df
#     A    B    C  D
#0    0    0    0  0
#1    0    0    0  0
#2    0    0    0  0
#3    A    B    C  D
#4  NaN  NaN  NaN  0
```

So it seams that, for some reason the DataFrame header is added as the new row instead of the actual values. Am I doing something wrong? I noted that this only happens when I set the size of the table with `index=range(5)`. If I do not set the size of the table adding columns and rows is working like expected. However, I would like to pre-allocate the table due to performance issues.

Comment: This is very strange.  Especially since if you repeat the `df.loc[3]` line twice, you get the expected result.  My guess is that it has to do with the differing datatypes

Comment: I think the last example (where row becomes `A B C D`) should be expected behaviour. See also [Updating a pandas DataFrame row with a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383127/updating-a-pandas-dataframe-row-with-a-dictionary). Doesn't explain the inconsistent treatment, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with the datatypes. When you create a dataframe without specifying any data, it automatically assigns datatype `object` to all columns.

Create your dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('A', 'B', 'C'), index=range(5), data=0)
```